# Autoloading of data of json deserialized object

Tags: java, jackson, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm using Jackson and Ebean on Play framework 2, currently I implemented these two models:

```
@Entity
class User {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    public String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public Office office;

    public static Finder<Long, User> find = new Finder<>(User.class);
}


@Entity
class Office {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    public static Finder<Long, Office> find = new Finder<>(Office.class);
}
```

In the database I already have two offices inserted:

```
Office Table    
ID      Name
1       London
2       Munich
```

And this is the Controller code:

```
public Result testInsert() {
    User user = Json.fromJson(request().body().asJson(), User.class);
    user.save();

    return Json.toJson(user);
}
```

Currently to let it work i have to pass this json:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Test",
    "office" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "London"
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to referencethe office only by name, in this way:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Test",
    "office" : {
        "name" : "London"
    }
}
```

And I would like to be able to create a new office row only if this does not already exist, there is any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you could add the `@JsonIgnore` annotation over the ID Field of the Office Model and create a method on the Office Class `findByName(String name)`, which would return an office entry.

Comment: That works amazing, thanks! (sorry for the delay in the answer)